# Verb that means "flutter" without the connotation of control

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, connotation

I need a verb that describe the phenomenon that occurs when a wing (like those of birds, or, for that matter, insects) is caught in a strong transverse breeze.  I was going to use the word *flutter*, but it seems to me that saying "its wings fluttered" implies that the wings in question were being controlled (at least to a certain extent) by the being to which they are attached.  Is there a word (or a short phrase if necessary, but a single word would be ideal) that means the same as *flutter* but without the mentioned connotation of control?

Comment: [flap](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flap): *intr. v.* 1 to sway loosely, usually with a noise of striking and especially when moved by wind

Comment: There's nothing about "flutter" that implies the presence or absence of control.  Leaves flutter in the breeze.  And "flutter" in an aircraft often indicates lack of adequate control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe instead of attaching the verb to the wings, you can attach it to the breeze instead?

> "The breeze *whiffled* the bird's feathers."

Merriam's definition: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whiffle

or if you really wanted to attach the verb to the wing, another suggestion would be *quiver*. While it is not directly synonymous to "flutter", it has the same action, which is the light shaking of the feathers.  But if you used this it would probably appear that it was due to the cold.

> "Its wings *quivered*."

Merriam's definition of quiver: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quiver

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't even think of rearranging the sentence; also, I really like *whiffle*.  :)

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame no problem! if you think this helped you, perhaps you could accept my answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

Flailed.  Flail.  wave or swing or cause to wave or swing wildly.
"his arms were flailing helplessly"

Comment: "Flail" actually has a stronger connotation of control than "flutter", as far as I'm aware.  :/

Answer (score 1):

How about [flitter?](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/flitter)

**flitter** - verb - Move quickly in an apparently random or purposeless manner.

**flitter** - noun - A fluttering movement.

Comment: Only butterflies and small birds flitter.

Comment: No, that is [flitted.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/flit)  A wing can flitter.  You just need to believe.